# Need help analysing results of an autocorrelations test result

Tags: random-walk, market-efficiency

I am a analysing weak-form efficiency of the NIFTY 100 Index (01-01-2014 to 31-01-2024). The first four lags have high p-value, hence they show randomness. however, all the rest of the lags do show some evidence of weak correlation, as they have low p-values and the correlation values are between 0 and +-0.025. What inferences should I draw from it? Should I ignore lags 1-4 and conclude with the existence of inefficiency? I also did a runs test and got a Z-value of -3.947 with p-value of 0.001
[image]